# Powershell don't catch exception from NewWebServiceProxy

Tags: web-services, powershell, exception, new-webserviceproxy

I have a problem with catching exception from NewWebServiceProxy cmdlet

```
try {
    $myService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://localhost/someservice.svc"
}
catch {
    Write-Log ([string]::Format("Error : {0}", $_.Exception.Message))
}
```

When I run it i get this unhandled exception : New-WebServiceProxy :

> The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. At
>   C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\d052b604-38ad-4827-b952-4ebc66e79c69.ps1:2
>   char:18
>   +     $myService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri `"http://localhost/someservice.svc"`
>   +                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (`http://localhost/someservice.svc:Uri`) [New-WebServiceProxy], WebExc
>   eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy

Somebody could ask me why try catch do not catch this exception ? Thanks for any aswer

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the most common issues while catching an unhandled exception in powershell. You need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` in the command `New-WebServiceProxy`

```
try {
    $myService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://localhost/someservice.svc" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]{
    Write-Log ([string]::Format("Error : {0}", $_.Exception.Message))
}
```

Updated: To catch Http exception include `[System.Net.WebException]` as noted by **Keith Hill** in the comment below.

Comment: Thanks it work, but the exception that I catch now is diffrent then exception above (HTTP status 404). Actual catched exception :
`There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/someservice.svc'`. Can I catch the 404 exception ?

Comment: I think you want to catch [System.Net.WebException].

Comment: Yes, but even when i add `catch [System.Net.WebException]` ps don't catch it.

Comment: I try call a request `try {
 $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost/someservice.svc")
 $response = $request.GetResponse()
} catch {
 Write-Error ([string]::Format("Response from request : {0}", $_.Exception.Message))
}` And catch give me this : `Exception c
alling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
`

Comment: So if you are doing System.Net.WebRequest then you need to check this on catching 404. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090849/random-webrequest-results-with-powershell

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was doing something more like

```
try{
    New-WebServiceProxy -URI $webURL -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            SOAPStatus = 'Failed'
            SOAPException = $_.Exception.Message
            SOAPInnerException = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
        } 
    }
    catch {
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            SOAPStatus = 'Failed'
            SOAPError = $_.Exception.Message
        } 
    }
```

By catching the inner exception I found I would get the web response as well if there was an issue with it. Which usually in these cases there was something like this for output:

SOAPStatus         : Failed
SOAPException      : There was an error downloading 'http://webserviceurl.com:1010/SystemServiceQuery'.

SOAPInnerException : The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Of course you could then capture what type of innerexception and give more useful feedback to your users and such.